# Не выводятся данные в таблицу при старте приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core

Не понимаю почему данный код не выводит таблицу в `DataGrid`, в прошлой программе, откуда собственно и скопирован код всё прекрасно работало.

```
private void Table_Update()
{
    context.Users.Load();
    UsersGrid.ItemsSource = context.Users.Local;
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Table_Update();
}
```

Comment: А Table_Update вообще срабатывает?

Comment: а как проверить?

Comment: Или пошаговой отладкой, или вставить туда MessageBox.Show, или Trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В XAML окна подпишитесь на событие `Window.Loaded`.

```xml
<Window ...
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

Или в конструкторе окна

```
Loaded += Window_Loaded;
```

Comment: Как я мог пропустить. Спасибо, помогло!